# Replacing "#", "$", "%", "&", and "_" with "\#", "\$", "\%", "\&", and "\_"

Tags: bash, latex, sed, escaping, grep

I have a plain text document, which I want to compile inside LaTeX. However, sometimes it has the characters, "#", "$", "%", "&", and "_". To compile properly in LaTeX, I must first replace these characters with  "#", "\$", "\%", "\&", and "_". I have used this line in `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\#/\\\#/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\$/\\\$/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\%/\\\%/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\&/\\\&/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\_/\\\_/g' ./file.txt
```

Is this correct?

Unfortunately, the file is too large to open in any GUI software, so checking if my `sed` line is correct with a text editor is difficult. I tried searching with `grep`, but the search does not work as expected (e.g. below, I searched for any lines containing "$"):

```
grep "\$" file.txt
```

- What is the best way to put "\" in front of these characters?
- How can I use `grep` to successfully check the lines with the replacements?

Comment: Can you guarantee you don't have any special characters which are ALREADY escaped?

Comment: How does the grep work, if not as expected?

Comment: When I run `grep "\$" file.txt` it seems to be printing everything out or nearly everything. I don't know why it is printing so much text out, as "$" is quite rare.

Comment: I think it is unlikely there are already escaped characters in the document. "\" appears quite frequently, but I don't know of any situations where it is used as an escape character.

Comment: Try `grep '\\\$' file.txt`. If you don't escape the backslash (and the dollar sign), then the dollar sign is escaped which tells `grep` to look for a literal "$" (instead of the end of the line - since "$" has a special meaning in regexes).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do the replacement with a single call to `sed`:

```
sed -i -E 's/([#$%&_\])/\\&/g' file.txt
```

The `&` in the replacement text fills in for whichever single character is enclosed in parentheses. Note that since `\` is the LaTeX escape character, you'll have to escape it as well in the original file.

Comment: The parentheses aren't necessary. Some versions of `sed` don't support `-E`, but use `-r` instead. Some versions of `sed` require an extension after `-i`, but since the OP didn't provide one in the question it's safe to assume it's not needed.

Comment: Good points, all. I was going to mention that -E would depend on the version is sed in use, but must have deleted it from the final version.

Comment: Actually you probably want to change `\` to `\textbackslash` since `\\` breaks the line.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i 's/\#/\\\#/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\$/\\\$/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\%/\\\%/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\&/\\\&/g' ./file.txt
sed -i 's/\_/\\\_/g' ./file.txt
```

You don't need the `\` on the first (search) string on most of them, just `$` (it's a special character, meaning the end of a line; the rest aren't special). And in the replacement, you only need two `\\`, not three.  Also, you could do it all in one with several `-e` statements:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/#/\\#/g'  \
           -e 's/\$/\\$/g' \
           -e 's/%/\\%/g'  \
           -e 's/&/\\&/g'  \
           -e 's/_/\\_/g' file.txt
```

You don't need to double-escape anything (except the `\\`) because these are single-quoted. In your `grep`, `bash` is interpreting the escape on the `$` because it's a special character (specifically, a sigil for variables), so `grep` is getting and searching for just the `$`, which is a special character meaning the end of a line. You need to either single-quote it to prevent `bash` from interpreting the `\` (`'\$'`, or add another pair of `\\`: `"\\\$". Presumably, that's where you're getting the`\` from, but you don't need it in the `sed` as it's written.

Comment: Since "$" is special, does it need three `\` (e.g. `\\\`) in front?

Comment: @Village Not in the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that bash itself is handling those escapes.

1. What you have looks right to me.  But warning: it will also doubly escape e.g. a `\#` that is already escaped.  If that's not what you want, you might want to modify your patterns to check that there isn't a preceding \ already.
2. $ is used for bash command substitution syntax.  I guess `grep "\\$" file.txt` should do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I do not respond for `sed`, the other answers are good enougth ;-)

You can use `less` as viewer to check your huge file (or `more`, but `less` is more comfortable than `more`).

For searching, you can use `fgrep`: it ignores regular expression => `fgrep '\$'` will really search for text `\$`. `fgrep` is the same as invoking `grep -F`.

EDIT:
`fgrep '\$'` and `fgrep "\$"` are different. In the second case, `bash` interprets the string and will replace it by a single character: `$` (i.e. `fgrep` will search for `$` only).