# Why is my file filled with extbar after running sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Based on the information at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48933/which-symbols-need-to-be-escaped-in-context, I want to prepare a file for use with ConTeXt. I need to make several replacements:

- Replace `#` with `\#`.
- Replace `%` with `\percent`.
- Replace `|` with `\textbar`.
- Replace `$` with `\textdollar`.
- Replace `_` with `\textunderscore`.
- Replace `~` with `\textasciitilde`.
- Replace `{` with `\textbraceleft`.
- Replace `}` with `\textbraceright`.

I have tried using the information from [Replacing "#", "$", "%", "&", and "_" with "\#", "\$", "\%", "\&", and "\_"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950527/replacing-and-with-and) to do these replacements:

```
sed -i 's/\&/\\\&/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\#/\\\#/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\%/\\\percent/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\|/\\\textbar/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\$/\\\textdollar/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\_/\\\textunderscore/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\~/\\\textasciitilde/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\{/\\\textbraceleft/g' ./File.csv
sed -i 's/\}/\\\textbraceright/g' ./File.csv
```

Unfortunately, when I run these scripts, the entire file is changed to a bunch of strange letters, numbers, and the words "extbar" everywhere.

- How can I make these replacements?
- Why is "extbar" appearing in my file after running these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do

```
sed -i 's/|/\\\textbar/g' ./File.csv
sed reads it as s/|/\\\textbar/g  \\ becomes \ and \t becomes tab character.
```

Try

```
sed -i "s/|/\\\textbar/g"
```

or

```
sed -i 's/|/\\textbar/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<\!  >Village.sed
s/&/\\&/g
s/#/\\#/g
s/%/\\percent/g
s/|/\\textbar/g
s/\$/\\textdollar/g
s/_/\\textunderscore/g
s/~/\\textasciitilde/g
s/{/\\textbraceleft/g
s/}/\\textbraceright/g
!
sed -f Village.sed ./File.csv
```

Not sure why "extbar" is appearing in your file probably to do with the line `s/\|/\\\textbar/g` where `\|` means alternation.

See here:

```
echo foo | sed 's/\|/\\bar/'
\barfoo
echo foo | sed 's/|/\\bar/'
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use four backslashes instead of the to escape. They are evaluated twice. Following, you have the character `\t`as replacement, followed by the string `'extbar'`(from \textbar)